# Is there a way to declare a action result?

Tags: struts2

I have this exact same line in 5 places in my struts xml -

```
<result name="error" type="json"><param name="root">response</param></result>
```

Is there a way i can declare this as some sort of custom result and include it in the 5 places i'm using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have to use it at multiple places instead define this as global result.

```
<global-results>
    <result name="error" type="json">
       <param name="root">response</param>
    </result>
</global-results>
```

So when your action will return error it will use this result from the global result and use it.

But if you want something like

```
<action name="someaction" class="somepackage.someAction">
   <result name="error" type="json">ReferSomeOhterResult</result>
</action>
```

this is not possible, you can only chain, redirect to a different action but one result cannot refer to another result.